# Is it possible to implement the CONNECT HTTP method with the Snap framework?

Tags: haskell, tunneling, haskell-snap-framework, http-method, http-tunneling

I'm looking into possibilities how to implement the CONNECT HTTP method that allows [tunneling data over HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_tunneling). However, I couldn't find a way how to implement bi-directional processing within one Snap request. The closest thing I found was [transformRequestBody](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.8.0.1/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:transformRequestBody)

```
transformRequestBodySource :: (forall a. Enumerator Builder IO a) -> Snap ()
```

but this only transforms request input into response output, while I need to process input and output simultaneously to relay data to the requested target resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is via escapeHttp. I discovered this by looking at [the source for websockets-snap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-snap-0.9.0.0/docs/src/Network-WebSockets-Snap.html), which presumably is the right way to upgrade a connection.

For reference, in the WAI world this is handled via the `responseRaw` function.